# Can airlines leave you stranded?

Tags: airlines, connecting-flights, ryanair, self-transfer

I am new to this, so explain stuff that might seem obvious to you. I'm seeing conflicting information when searching online.

Say I have booked an itinerary with separate airlines:

```
A -> B, B -> C
C -> B, B -> A
```

This is four separate flights, meaning neither of the transfers are guaranteed. The A -> B, B -> A is a return flight package, and the B -> C, C -> B one too.

What I'm worried about is that an airline cancels a flight in a place where I don't want to be, say the B -> C trip or the C -> B one (which is my holiday destination, so being stuck there would suck), and maybe refunds my £38, but leaves me stranded. Since they consider this a point-to-point purchase, I have no "home" base that I could considered away from, leaving them with no responsibility to take me back. Is that how it works?

If the C -> B flight is delayed, can they just put me on a later flight, so I miss the B -> A one, since that is not part of their problem, and B is my home as far as they are concerned?

This is in Europe.

Feel free to mention anything that might seem relevant, even if not directly a answer to the question.

Thank you.

Comment: "_This is in Europe._" - do you mean "This is in the EU"? They're not the same

Comment: Not your question, but just **don't do this**. Book both legs on a single ticket, or ideally get a direct flight. If there absolutely are no single-ticket options (e.g. C is an obscure location only reachable via local airlines that don't code share), either do some serious research on insurance policies or leave a 1+ day extended layover at B on the way back so that you can make alternate arrangements if your return flight is delayed or cancelled.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: I’d rather say, **only do this if you’re willing to accept the risk**.  Most times I’ve price-compared in recent years, suitable insurance/flexibility options have been pretty expensive — enough that in purely monetary terms, they were clearly worse than a smallish chance of buying last-minute rearrangements out-of-pocket.  The insurance also provides some reduction in disruption/stress, so people may reasonably feel that’s worth paying for — but it’s a personal judgement call, and taking the risk oneself can definitely be the right choice sometimes.

Comment: I see Ryanair as a tag.|| **IF** this includes Ryanair it should be in the question near the top and **in bold**.  Rynair very greatly affects the advice given. If they are the last leg then maybe it is not much different than if any other airline was. BUT IF Ryanair are an intermediate leg it may significantly affect the advice given. || Ryanair are not only known for their bad service BUT they boast publicly of how they purposefully provide bad service, || [I've flown RyanAir once (two legs: England-Dublin return) . It was fun and we had no problems BUT we saw why people say what they do.

Comment: "RyanAir wrecked my travel plans, but on the upside, I saved £100" said literally no one.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : *"they boast publicly of how they purposefully provide bad service"* could you please provide some examples?

Comment: @vsz I'll see if I can find references **BUT** I have read explicit instances of this by the top executive wit not just a statement but some expansion. Really.

Comment: @vsz  Not quite what you asked but [this](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4898590/Ryanair-marketing-boss-boasts-busy-week.html) gives a good idea - purposefully provocative posts re his jetsetting while cancelling 400,000+ passenger-flights, 250,000 with no refunds offered, for allegedly spurious reasons in an unknown number of cases. || What I mentioned IS available explicitly. But a read of Ryanair related posts will leave you in (literally) no doubt. || I'd vanishingly seldom slang anyone publicly (and Henry Kissinger is now dead) BUT Ryanair are the lowest of the low, by design.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I have seen price differences of over $2000 using a single airline ticket compared to multiple.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : the link you posted does not support your statement at all. He did not boast that he purposely arranged for bad service, he actually boasted for how busy he was working and trying to make things work.

Comment: @vsz What I said was  Not quite what you asked but this gives a good idea" - there are direct claims made and they will turn up in due course. || If you do not think that is what the article described then other statements may be equally unpersuasive.|| I started to condense some of the points made but space permits not. They are there for the reading.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : *"they are there for the reading"* - **where?** Could you post links? Just one link, where Ryanair publicly boasted that they intentionally provided bad service? I'm not your enemy, I'm not an advocate of Ryanair, but if you said that such official public statements are commonplace, surely you can post at least one link to one of them?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have booked a return flight A -> B -> A with AirGreen, and a return flight B -> C -> B with AirRed on separate bookings. This can indeed leave you stranded.

For example, let us assume that your C -> B flight with AirRed gets cancelled short-notice. This leaves AirRed responsible for getting you to B as soon as possible, and to provide you with food and accommodation (if the delay is long enough) in C until then. Since this is happening in Europe, they might also owe you compensation under EC 261 (depending on the distance, how long the delay is, and whether the airline can blame circumstances beyond their control). However, AirRed is not liable for subsequent inconvenience this may cause you. Once they have delivered you to B (and paid the EC 261 compensation, if applicable), they've done their duty.

If you are not at the gate at airport B at the appropriate time for your flight B -> A with AirGreen, AirGreen can declare you a no-show, cancel your flight, keep your money and be done with you.

Note that the same issue might happen even if AirRed and AirGreen are the same airline, if you have two separate bookings. Only if you have a genuine connecting flight the airline is actually obliged to return you to A.

Your travel insurance might cover such a situation, but check carefully before relying on that. Otherwise I'd avoid making such a booking unless I could afford to book a new last-minute ticket from B to A.

Comment: Important note: insurance only makes sense if you can't afford to cover the loss out of pocket. If you can pay up the cost of a last-minute ticket from B to A + a last-minute hotel room, you don't need insurance.

Comment: @JonathanReez Whilst this is true, travel insurance is so cheap that I would be surprised if it was ever more economical to risk purchasing another flight. That, plus the extra cover travel insurance provides means, IMO, it is never sensible to travel without it. Too many people get stranded abroad with medical conditions and face serious repatriation bills because they didn’t buy travel insurance.

Comment: But who do I buy this insurance with? Since each leg is separate, checking yes on their insurance option wouldn't do anything about missing my connection, right?

Comment: I doubt that any travel insurance would cover that. They tend to have A LOT of exclusions.

Comment: Please note that "Europe" and "EU"/"EEA"/"EFTA" are not the same thing. There are many flights in Europe that are not covered under EU regulations (for example, İzmir to Tirane)

Comment: Inside Europe the ec261 compensation will, in most cases, cover a substantial part or all of the last minute ticket, so the risk in doing this is not too bad. The biggest risk is that the flight is cancelled for bad weather or so and you don't get a compensation.

Comment: @Darren: Insurance is a profitable business, which means they take in more in premiums than they pay out, by definition. It is *never* economically advantageous to purchase insurance in a strict expected-value sense, but most people are [risk averse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion) to some degree. The proper calculation is therefore just how risk averse you are relative to the cost and likelihood of purchasing a new flight.

Comment: @Kevin of course they make profit, but taking more in premiums than claims paid out *overall* is irrelevant to an individual traveller. I can get a policy that covers me for a single trip to Europe for as little as £10 (43, no medical conditions). Given I could potentially face tens of thousands of pounds in medical and repatriation bills should I fall ill or have an accident abroad, why wouldn’t I spend the price of two pints of beer to protect me? The news is replete with people who didn’t make that decision and came to rue the day.

Comment: I lied, it was actually an annual multi-trip policy.

Comment: Also, I see you’re American. I have a feeling that Americans are generally more reluctant to take out any kind of insurance (e.g. contents insurance - renters insurance to you, I think). I’ve never heard of anyone in the UK not having contents insurance. Whether that’s because it’s cheaper here, the industry is more heavily regulated or because in the US it’s seen as “socialism” the same way as universal healthcare, I don’t know.

Comment: @Kevin You have misunderstood the economics of aggregating/redistributing risk. It's quite often economically advantageous to purchase insurance; you pay an insurer a small fee so that you do not need to keep a large sum of money tied up in case (for example) your house burns down. A sum of money you may not even have in the first place. And this also makes sense for societies; it is an ineffective use of funds for *everyone* to have a large sum of money tied up this way. A shared backup with a large enough pool of people so that the statistically required buy-in is very small just makes sense

Comment: @Darren American here: I don't know if the situation is different in Europe, but the last time I dealt with an insurance company, it was so aggravating I'm not sure it was worth the $300 I saved. It was quite difficult just to speak to a human on the phone. They are have also refused me medicines which my doctor prescribed, unless my doctor jumps through more bureaucratic hoops. I still insure against catastrophic losses, but for smaller risks which I can afford to bear I prefer to avoid dealing with these companies.

Comment: @academic I’ve never claimed on a travel policy, but my experience of claiming on home home and car policies is at least neutral, if not positive, so I assume the experience could be comparable. I imagine the industry is more heavily regulated here and in your specific case of medicines, it’s unlikely the same would occur here thanks to the socialised healthcare of most European countries.

Comment: @academic Indeed it makes far less sense to insure against potential costs that can be paid out of pocket, e.g. phone insurance. I do get the impression that insurance in the US is far more expensive and far more cumbersome / less customer-friendly than in the EU countries I'm familiar with. I've never spent more than an hour or two on paperwork and phone calls for an insurance claim (such as someone totaling my car or needing to lawyer up against eviction).

Comment: @JonathanReez That is FAR too broad a statement. Many, many travel insurances in Europe are annual and part of your general home insurance, and they cover a lot more than just flight delays/cancellations and lost luggage. It may not be necessary to have a travel insurance specifically for those things, but it is NEVER advisable to travel without travel insurance altogether. I’ve seen too many lives ruined by insane expenses for medical treatment and repatriation with no insurance to cover.

Comment: @academic Insurance in Europe is generally a very different beast, yes. We don’t have the whole concept of ‘provider networks’, for one thing, and claims are handled much more automatically with much less reticence. I have claimed on my travel or home insurance about five or six times in total (all non-urgent issues), and each time, I simply filled out a form online, and that was it. After a couple of weeks, the amount I claimed for was paid out to me directly to my bank account – in one case (stolen phone) actually _more_ than I requested, and more than the phone was worth.

Comment: @JonathanReez there is a substantial difference between "not needed" and "doesn't make sense". When you buy travel insurance, you're not buying _the ability to have your surprise costs covered_, you're buying _the fact that you don't have to cover your surprise costs yourself, even if you could_. I find it slightly astonishing that a travel.se moderator doesn't appear to understand travel insurance...

Comment: @AakashM [please see my answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/105661/9009). Note that there's a difference between *health* insurance and *travel* insurance. Health costs can easily run up to $100k+ depending on your illness and destination. Travel losses are usually capped at around $10k at most and getting insurance to pay up for them is often a nightmare.

Comment: @JonathanReez that answer, which doesn't include any mention of probability or expectation, confirms my belief that you don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you'll be stranded. If the connection were on the same airline, they MIGHT sort you to your actual destination at their discretion. easyJet did so in March when I was denied boarding Larnaca-Liverpool and had a connection Liverpool-Belfast - they sorted me to Belfast via the Netherlands. With separate airlines though, no chance unless it's a single booking through a third-party with a self-transfer guarantee.

Comment: It is safe to assume that RyanAir, on the other hand, will not lift a single finger more than they absolutely have to in order to help you.

Comment: Possibly the first nice thing I've heard someone say about Easyjet. Interesting.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Their ground operations folks have been awesome to me in this context (I've been denied boarding 9 times in a year on their flights)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers, note that outside Europe, and specifically in Asia, depending on the airlines, they might accommodate you, depending on their quality of service (ie forget LCCs), and your status with them.

I have occasionally run into similar cases, especially with B = Thailand, eg Laos to BKK with TG, BKK to HKG with CX, and Thai Airways did their best to get me to my CX flight in time: car from the plane to the next gate, staff accompanying me, etc.

And when that effort wasn't enough and I missed the flight, CX rebooked me on the next flight - I  have been a Gold member for ages, so that probably helped.

And the luggage was put on the proper plane, because TG and CX interline.

So bottom line, you might want to elaborate on the airports and airlines involved.

Comment: I have no experience with RyanAir (or other European LCCs). My experience in Asia is extensive mostly due to the fact that before Covid I was travelling for work at least 3 weeks per month, for 15 years. So even with a low frequency of incidents, it does stack up... :-)

Comment: AirFrance fly Billund - Paris - Marrakesh and will sell you a connecting ticket. It would need to be a big saving to make me choose separate RyanAir tickets over that.

Comment: @JohnBig Since you’re flying from Denmark: virtually all Danish travel insurances (by which I mean annual ones as part of your home insurance – short-term insurances sometimes have vastly different coverages) will cover reasonable extra costs incurred if you end up stranded due to a missed or cancelled flight, assuming that (a) missing the flight was unforeseen and not your fault, and (b) your original travel plan adheres to the minimum transfer times at all airports. There will generally be a cap of about DKK 10–15,000 (≈ €1,500–2,000) per insured passenger.

Comment: So far I never had long enough delays to miss a transfer, but from your description this seems to happen often enough that I can't just gamble that they'll be on time? I just don't want to be terrified the whole time while I'm away. The airline is the one I mentioned in the tag. It's all with them. Judging from their reputation, they seem to not be very keen on making people happy. Airports are in the EU -> no longer on the EU -> never in the EU.